# How to efficiently draw rotating paths on a canvas

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, path, surfaceview

I'm making an app in which the user draws patterns (drawn and stored as `Path` objects) onto a `Canvas` on a `SurfaceView`. The app does some basic animations on the paths including constantly rotating them. I've read that a common optimisation for `Path` drawing is to cache them into a `Bitmap` so that all the bezier logic isn't repeated each frame. I tried this but it's making things worse. My best guess is that having to rotate bitmaps by an arbitrary angle every frame is too expensive. Is this a likely diagnosis? Bitmap rotation is very slow, right? Is there a way around this?

Comment: You should just rotate the `Canvas`, not the `Bitmap`.

Comment: @kcoppock: I'm doing that, just worded it wrong. Surely it amounts to the same calculations?

Comment: Not really, no. You'd have to make a larger copy of the bitmap to actually rotate the bitmap itself. Rotating the Canvas would use the same bitmap. Anyway, it's unlikely that this is your performance problem. Profile your app using Traceview through DDMS and take a look at what's actually slowing you down.

Comment: @kcoppock: Does it not have to recalculate the position of every pixel in the bitmap?

Comment: From a low level, I can't say exactly what happens, but it's all done on the GPU and should be nearly free to execute. This goes for scale, translate, rotate, or alpha Canvas changes.